# How do I debug a failing ember-cli build?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an oldish `ember-cli` project. It's Ember 3.5, but it came from 2.x initially (and has some `bower` components). It used to build and deploy fine. But now I started it from a clean computer. I changed nothing, except reinstall its dependencies.

```
npm install
./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember build -prod
```

After some processing, I see the following error:

> ajv.js: property right of assignmentexpression expected node to be of a type ["expression"] but instead got null

I try to lock some versions (i.e. remove `~` and `^` from `package.json` version numbers and run `npm install` again) and I either get the same error or something equally vague.

> async.js: Property object of MemberExpression expected node

Trying the same with bower results in other error messages:

> uglifier: Unexpected token: punc (:)

There were others but I didn't write everything down. I've spend quite some time on this. The problem is that every error, including their stack trace, doesn't really help me find where the problem is.

How can I debug this? How can I fix this? I thought `package-lock.json` was made to prevent this, but I guess I'm in dependency hell either way. Perhaps it was a problem with `bower.json`? There is no `bower-lock.json`.

Comment: Did you verified that you are using the same nodejs version on both machines?

Comment: Yes, I used node 8 in stead of 10 on purpose because I had used that originally.

Comment: It does sound possible that it’s your bower dependencies that have changed. Are you able to get a copy of them off the computer that was working to see?

Comment: I've indeed restored bower dependencies from an old old backup one by one until the build didn't fail anymore. I believe that bower dependencies are deprecated now, but they keep tagging along in this long-lived project.

If you write up your comment into an answer with some tips about how to get rid of bower completely, I will accept your answer.